# Change a string in a column to an integer in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace, data-science

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JzAIa.png)table of movie data

[image]

As you can see the column of release date puts the month in a string.
I want to change all of them into numbers.
For example, Dec 18, 2009 can just be 12. I am not interested in the year.

Update: I think I got it. They still come out as objects when I do .info() but at least I was able to get to the number

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select month in a pandas date column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70103974/how-to-select-month-in-a-pandas-date-column)

Answer (score 1):

You can convert it to datetime and use `Series.dt.month`

```py
df['release date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['release date']).dt.month
```

```
print(df)

   release date
0            12
```